Reversible Two-Four-Three Swap

I'm trying to solve this. I'm very new to circuit-based reversible computing and have studied about gates. I'm trying to see how can I solve this.
As far as I've come, I see that I might need to put a NOT gate over the qubit a so as to build control for the further qubits. How can I move forward?

I like Quirk as a quick way to mock up such circuits.  In particular this circuit might work.  Indeed letting the top qubit be $|a\rangle$ with the bottom qubit being $|d\rangle$, you can use a NOT gate $\oplus$ before and after the first Fredkin gate, as you guessed might work.


This is great. Thank you for the resources. I'm trying to get into understanding reversible systems and I found one of these problems on the portal. Is there a place where I can practice more problems like these? Like maybe Leetcode for quantum circuits?

Thanks. No idea where to find other examples. If you find a good bank of questions consider editing your post to add a link for the community!
